# Putting a sum of rational numbers over a common denominator

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This comes up whenever we try to put a sum of rational numbers over a common denominator.

Let $\mathrm{lcm}$ denote the function that returns the lowest common multiple of a sequence of natural numbers. Then supposing we have a sequence of natural numbers $b$ with $n$ terms, we can define a new sequence $c$ with $n$ terms such that $c_i = \mathrm{lcm}(b)/b_i$. Under these definitions, we have that for all sequences $a$ with $n$ terms it holds that

$$\frac{a_1}{b_1} + \cdots + \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{a_1 c_1 + \cdots + a_n c_n}{\mathrm{lcm}(b)}.$$

Furthermore, the terms of $c$ are natural numbers; and, most importantly, they're relatively prime (but not necessarily pairwise so).

My questions are as follows.

1. Does this theorem have a name? It seems pretty fundamental.
2. The theorem is obviously useful for computation, but does it have more conceptual applications?
3. Does the function that turns a sequence $b$ into a sequence $c$ such that $c_i = \mathrm{lcm}(b)/b_i$ have a special name, or notation associated with it?

Comment: I wouldn't even call this a theorem

Comment: @Ethan, yes now that you mention it, neither would I. I'm actually more interested in the function $b \mapsto c$ rather than where it comes from. The "theorem" was mainly just motivation.

Comment: The least common multiple of a sequence of integers can be converted into an expression involving the greatest common divisor of that sequence of integers, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_factor.

Comment: What do you mean by 'conceptual applications'?

Comment: @Ethan, you know, like a proof of a theorem. "For all natural $n$ there exist naturals $a$ and $b$ such that..."

Comment: I still don't understand, your not asking for a proof are you? The equality of the two expressions you posted are equal by your definition of each term in the sequence.

Comment: @Ethan, no. The proof is trivial. What I'm asking is, does the theorem show up in any interesting proofs?